# Is it good practice to keep Cursors in Try catch block?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Most of the time when I write a cursor in SQL Server, I keep it in a try/catch block.  In the catch block I deallocate and close the activities of the cursor.

What is your opinion?  Is this a good practice?

Comment: It's not good practice to use cursors unless no set-based solution is available. Otherwise you can do deallocation and close activities in the catch if you're afraid it will fail.

Comment: Why would you deallocate and close in the `CATCH`? What if no error occurs in your `TRY`? When will then your cursor be deallocated and closed?

Comment: @CyberDude I mean i am doing it twice, once in catch block and other with general execution

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 1):

Think it through and I think you will agree that try/catch for a cursor is bad practice.

If you encounter an error when declaring or opening a cursor then the CLOSE in the catch block won't work, it needs a successfully opened cursor. So you shouldn't include these parts in a using.

Move on a little to the loop and FETCH. I can't see an error happening in a simple loop statement, and if it happens with the FETCH then @@FETCH_STATUS gets set to -1 instead of an error being raised. So there is no point in including those parts.

Now we are onto the operation you are completing with the cursor. If an error happens here you either want to fix it and continue, log it and continue step on to the next row, or explicitly break the loop within the error handling of the operation. Your solution would jump you out of the operation where a catch block might have done some good.

After you finish the loop, either because of a break, a fetch error or the end of the records you can just close and deallocate without a catch block, there's no need to repeat yourself.

So you are writing useless code, moving away from the causes of an error and potential resolutions, and at worst replacing an otherwise reported error with one about CLOSE being called on an unopened cursor.